# TIdTCPClient to SSL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

When I connect to 80 port, plain text web site using TIdTCPClient component, all works fine, data is received without a problem, but, when I connect to 443 port, SSL web site, data **not always** came.

Maybe something with my receive data block ? Need advice.

```
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    SetLength(data, 0);
    ws.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data, -1);
    if Length(data) = 0 then
      break;

    // processing_my(data);
  end;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening the connection to an other port to have it secure is not enough. To connect to anything SSL, you'll need an IOHandler that supports it, such as [TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=delphi%20TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL)

Comment: yes I know thanks. But the problem was in other, my ReadTimeout was 5 sec, now I set it to 30 sec, and all works fine.

Comment: @waza And if this is not the solution, why you marked it as accepted? StackOverflow is supposed to work on a technical basis and you shouldn't accept answers based on sympathy.